# Plotly scatter map value error for 'size' property

Tags: python, plotly

I'm trying to create a scatter map for a dataframe with index= countries and columns= some variables (like below)

```
data= {'Ss': [14, 14, 30, 878], 'Cs': [20, 116, 321, 3883], 'Rs': [0, 0, 34, 1192]}
affs_df= pd.DataFrame(index= ['Argentina', 'Austria', 'Australia', 'United States'], data= data)

smfig = go.Figure()
col_names = affs_df.columns
for n in col_names:
    smfig.add_trace(go.Scattergeo(
        locationmode = 'country names',
        marker = dict(
            size= affs_df[n],
            line_color= 'rgb(40, 40, 40)',
            line_width= 0.5,
            sizemode= 'area'),
    name= n))

smfig.update_layout(
    title_text= 'Affiliations of publications',
    showlegend= True,
    geo= dict(
        scope= 'world',
        landcolor= 'rgb(217, 217, 217)'))
```

but I get that error:

```
ValueError: 
    Invalid value of type 'pandas.core.series.Series' received for the 'size' property of scattergeo.marker
```

I changed size feature to `size= affs_df[n].to_list()` but the result comes as an empty map!

Comment: Maybe you also need `locations = affs_df.index.values.tolist(),` inside `go.Scattergeo` ? (Together with `size= affs_df[n].to_list()`)

Comment: What does `import plotly; plotly.__version__` return?

Comment: @JohanC adding ``` locations ```  solved the problem, thanks

Comment: In the original version there was no way plotly could now the names of the countries. It's hard to test, as different versions of plotly need slightly different ways to get their parameters.